# Cleaner and idealistic way of migrating ant project to maven

Tags: java, maven

Trying to migrate an ant project to the maven project and was able to use translate to the maven project feature of the eclipse. Though I have an idea of working with maven projects so far, but still would like to know if there are any best practices to follow while migrating it.

Also, would really appreciate if anyone can help like how to set up the same on bamboo that would be ideal for all the working developers.

The steps achieved so far are :

1. Created pom.xml with all the required jars and repositories.
2. Created a local .m2 folder with dependencies present and installed.

I would like a meaningful transition from ant to maven. I know how things work on local but when it comes to deploying it to bamboo, I am a bit confused with so much distributed information on the internet. 
Any specific leads would be really helpful

Comment: "Created a local .m2 folder with dependencies present and installed." Usually, in a company you would set up your own Nexus/Artifactory server to manage the artifacts. If this project is small and does not depend on other projects of your company you can connect directly to MavenCentral to manage your dependencies. In either case, you usually do not need to manually curate the .m2 /repository folder.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for the prompt response. So you mean to say while deciding on the architecture , it should be via maven nexus repository etc rather than .m2. How should it be configured on bamboo in that case.

Comment: Never used bamboo, just Jenkins and Quickbuild. But generally, this is very similar to the local configuration. Put your Nexus/Artifactory into the settings.xml, set up the distributionManagement in the POM as well and run a maven command like `mvn clean deploy`.